# How can I get the size of a file using its URL without downloading it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/screensteps_live/step_images/adabys/manuals/2292/New_section____ddown.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=dsDSAw&Expires=2231231&Signature=AFNkandsakdIWwdwda%3D
```

Can I get the size of this PDF without downloading it or this is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You could make `HEAD` request and check if `Content-Length` header is set.

For exemple

```
curl -i -X HEAD http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/unanything/images/3/34/Captain_Obvious.jpg/revision/latest\?cb\=20111219154532
> ...
> Content-Length: 47103
> ...
```

Comment: Thanks great! That what I've been looking for! Could you please tell me, how can I define the response location url of my request?

Comment: The downside of using HEAD is a dynamically generated document might not have a content-length determinable by the server. It's one of those gotchas we can hit occasionally.

Comment: @ezelen42 sorry I didn't understand what you need

Comment: @fl00r it's okay! I've found what I needed))